# Can I replace a laptop screen with one of a different resolution?

Tags: laptop, display, lcd, resolution

I have a laptop with a busted screen, so I am going to install a replacement.
Does the replacement screen have to be the same resolution as the original?

Comment: Not only that: it has to be the same model number too.

Comment: Typically yes, unless someone has posted an article about that particular model of laptop that has been upgraded successfully. Its sort of rocket science to know how to upgrade on any particular make/model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be a different resolution as long as the laptop supports the display panel you are replacing the original display with.

For example a Dell Latitude D630 supports two [displays](http://www.dell.com/us/en/dfb/notebooks/latit_d630/pd.aspx?refid=latit_d630&cs=28&s=dfb), WXGA+ and WXGA. You should be able to swap up or down, but be sure that you get an inverter with the new display.

Comment: So, downgrading should be no problem?  The original resolution was 1600 x 1200, but the laptop is for my mom and that resolution may make things appear too small for her.

Comment: Downgrading shouldn't be a problem. I would look for a panel plus inverter.

Answer (score 0):

Worse, it has to be the same model number for a Dell. Sometimes the same model number is not the same panel it seems. Check to ensure the replacement screen has the inverter attached or the inverter holder attached to the screen - some don't- and the Dell d630 needs the inverter attached to the bottom of the panel.